# How to redirect to another page after clicking register React, Node, Express MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to redirect to < App /> only when the I click the submit button. I am using React for my frontend and Node with Express for my backend.

I know that I can use ejs files in express as frontend and use res.render("page") to redirect to another page. Now that I am using React as the frontend, I am struggling how to redirect to another page when I click my submit button.

Is there a redirecting method I can add in my newUser.save() so when the newUser.save() is executed, it will talk to my React and tell it to render < App />?

T**his is my server.js**

[image: this is my server.js]

**This is my click handler in react**

[image: this is my click handler in react]

Comment: Your API on storing/saving the data should return some response back to the front-end. In the front-end you can verify the response and accordingly route it to a different page.

Comment: How do I tell my newUser.save() to send a response to the front end?

Comment: you can use <Link> on your client-side to make redirecting after clicking the button. from 'react-router-dom'
or passport with authorization to auto redirect users^ when they already logged6 but it's much more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API is not returning any data

try this on the backend

```
newUser.save(function (err, createdUser) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return res.status(400).send(err)
  } return res.send(createdUser)
})
```

and on frontend using something like react router or window.location.href

```
axios.post("http://localhost:5000/new", newUser)
  .then(user => {
    console.log(user)
    window.location.href = "/path/to/route"
})
```

also try refactoring the backend code to use promises or async/await instead of callbacks

```
router.post('/post', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userData = {
      username: req.body.username,
      password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.passowrd, saltRounds)
    }
    const createdUser = await User.create(userData)

    return res.send(createdUser)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return res.status(400).sned(err)
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That window.location.href saved me.